# Saving session attributes in an Object(Java)

Tags: java, jsf-2, session-variables

How can I save session attributes on a class using Java and JSF?
Is there any annotation that helps me do it?
Help me out, I need some session attributes, and I guess would be better if I save them on Object. If You guys know the command too, to save in a different way, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

Just use a [`@SessionScoped`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/bean/SessionScoped.html) [`@ManagedBean`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/bean/ManagedBean.html).

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class SessionBean {

    private SomeObject someObject; // +getter+setter

}
```

You can access it from other managed beans by [`@ManagedProperty`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/bean/ManagedProperty.html).

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class OtherBean {

    @ManagedProperty(value="#{sessionBean}")
    private SessionBean sessionBean; // +setter

    public void someAction() {
        SomeObject someObject = sessionBean.getSomeObject();
        // ...
    }

}
```

Or if you really insist in storing it outside managed beans, use the session map.

```
Map<String, Object> sessionMap = externalContext.getSessionMap();
sessionMap.put("someObject", someObject);
```

It'll be available in other beans by

```
Map<String, Object> sessionMap = externalContext.getSessionMap();
SomeObject someObject = (SomeObject) sessionMap.get("someObject");
```

It maps under the covers to `HttpSession#get/setAttribute()`.

Answer (score 0):

EL expression to access objects in session map

```
<h:inputText id="sample" value="#{sessionScope.someProperty}"/>
```